# Función se cierra al ejecutar Try-Catch

Tags: java, android, try-catch

Antes de entrar en código he de decir 2 cosas.

- El código:

  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Solicitando datos...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  que hay dentro de ObtenerInfo(), lo muestra cada 5 segundo si elimino todo el Try-Catch que hay más abajo, de ahí supongo que el try-Catch tiene algo que ver.
- Y por otro lado, el mismo Try-Catch lo tengo en otra clase con un doInBackground() dentro del OnCreate y funciona bien, me trae los datos.

Desde el OnCreate llamo a ObtenerInfo cada 5 segundos.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 5000;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                ObtenerInfo();
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);
```

Resultado: Actividad se cierra, vuelve a la Actividad Main y Logcat se borra todo y vuelve iniciarse.

Opción 2 (por si os ayuda...)

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 5000;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){


                try {
                    ObtenerInfo();
                }catch(Exception e){ Log.e("TAG-HANDLER", e.getMessage());}

                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);
```

Resultado: No se cierra la Actividad y arroja este error cada 5 segundos: E/TAG-HANDLER: println needs a message

Función ObtenerInfo:

```
public void ObtenerInfo(){

            String[][] items2 = new String[10][10];
            URL url2;

            try {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ENTRO EN TRY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                url2 = new URL("http://energypanel.net/apps/movil/epconnect/update.php");
                //Abrir la conexión
                HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
                connection2.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" + " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");

                int respuesta2 = connection2.getResponseCode();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta2 == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "HTTP OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // preparo la cadena de entrada
                    InputStream in2 = new BufferedInputStream(connection2.getInputStream());
                    // la introduzco en un BufferedReader
                    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));

                    String line2;
                    while ((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                        result.append(line2);
                    }


                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                    String resultJSON2 = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");

                    // LEO LA RESPUESTA Y LA TRATO PARA ASIGNARLA A VARIOS TEXTVIEW
                   /* if (resultJSON2.equals("1")) {
                        JSONArray infoJSON2 = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray("items");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON
                        for (int i = 0; i < infoJSON2.length(); i++) {
                            items2[i][1] = infoJSON2.getJSONObject(i).getString("temp");
                            items2[i][2] = infoJSON2.getJSONObject(i).getString("alarmalp");
                            items2[i][3] = infoJSON2.getJSONObject(i).getString("alarmahp");
                            items2[i][4] = infoJSON2.getJSONObject(i).getString("alarmaht");

                            //SETS DATES
                            IdBufferIn.setText(items2[i][1]);

                            if(items2[i][2].equals("1")){
                                IdText1p.setTextColor(Color.rgb(198,27,000));
                                IdText1p.setEnabled(true);
                                IdText1p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            else{IdText1p.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}

                            if(items2[i][3].equals("1")){
                                IdText2p.setTextColor(Color.rgb(198,27,000));
                                IdText2p.setEnabled(true);
                                IdText2p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            else{IdText2p.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}

                            if(items2[i][4].equals("1")){
                                IdText3p.setTextColor(Color.rgb(198,27,000));
                                IdText3p.setEnabled(true);
                                IdText3p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            else{IdText3p.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
                        }
                    } else if (resultJSON2.equals("2")) {}*/
                }
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {  e.printStackTrace();  } 
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
            catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            catch(Exception e){ Log.e("TU-TAG-CONSTANTE", e.getMessage()); }

}
```

Comment: Puedes marcar exactamente donde esta lanzando el error o indicar cual es el error que lanza?

Comment: te diría que imprimas en e.toSring, un e.getMessage()
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

Así podrás saber cuál es el problema

(En cada uno de los catch XXXXExecption que tienes)

Comment: @Einer el caso es que no sé donde está el error, yo creo que es justo al empezar el try {. En el Logcat cuando se cierra la actividad desaparece todo y no muestra nngún error.

Comment: Abre el logcat y el mensaje de error que muestra ahi y publicalo en tu respuesta.

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz ya lo he puesto en los 3 catch pero no me muestra nada :(

Comment: @Einer como te digo, tengo el Logcat abierto y me aparece todo sin errores, pero cuando entro en esta actividad en concreto, la actividad se cierra, vuelve al Main y en Logcat se reinicia sin darme ningún error.

Comment: Pero para ver los errores en el logcat debes imprimirlos, de lo contrario no los veras. O sea, poner esto en cada `catch`:  **`Log.e("TU-TAG-CONSTANTE", e.getMessage());`** y claro, seleccionar la opción `error` cuando abras el logcat.

Comment: Si, tiene pinta que posiblemente no te salen los Toast porque palma la app como tal... mucho mejor que hagas el print por consola..  o con el Log.e que te dice @A.Cedano

Comment: @A.Cedano ya he puesto eso en cada catch y el Logcat también se reinicia, se borra todo y vuelve a empezar y no veo nada.

Comment: Intenta capturar una `Exception` en general escribiendo en el logcat el mensaje de error a ver qué pasa.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿Cómo hago eso?

Comment: Algo así: `} catch (Exception e) { Log.e("TU-TAG-CONSTANTE", e.getMessage());`

Comment: @A.Cedano Si agrego a la función ObtenerInfo() este catch: catch(Exception e). No se cierra la Actividad. Y si además en el run del handler pongo un try-catch con Exception e consigo que me muestre cada 5 segundos: "println needs a message"

Comment: ¿? no entiendo del todo tu comentario ni qué impacto tiene ese comportamiento en tu App. ¿?  ¿Si revisas el logcat **correctamente**,   o sea, seleccionando la opción `error`, ¿muestra algún tipo de error?

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y lo valoro muchísimo pero veo que insistes en que seleccione la opción "Error", que seleccione "Show Only selected application" y como ya dije varias veces está todo desde que cree post así. Y no, no aparece ningún error. Simplemente la Actividad se cierra y el Logcat se reinicia. Todo esto con tu catch agregado al final del resto de catch: catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  Log.e("TU-TAG-CONSTANTE2", e.getMessage()); }

Comment: @A.Cedano Si ves complejo darme una solución puedes revisar este otro post que he realizado para intentar hacer lo que quiero de una manera diferente, a lo mejor es más fácil: 
 https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157293/como-ejecutar-asynctask-cada-x-segundos

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor comentar todos esos `Toast`, al menos temporalmente? Me parece extraño que el logcat se reinicie. Si observas bien, hay varias opciones en la ventana del logcat: a la izquierda del todo el dispositivo, luego está la versión de la App, y luego  el tipo de errores que quieres ver (`Verbose, Debug, Info...` etc)  y luego  al final en el extremo derecho `Show only selected application`.  ¿Es así como lo estás revisando? Aunque la App se cerrase, deberías ver los errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, así es como lo tengo compañero, por favor revisa el código del primer post porque lo he actualizado con tus recomendaciones y con una aclaración, espero que te ayude a entenderlo todo.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de comprobar que la Actividad se cierra justo cuando llega a esta línea de código ( JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString()); )

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he solucionado con AsyncTask.

La función ObtenerInfo la he colocado dentro de:

```
public void SelectData(final String web){

        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[][]> {
            @Override
            protected String[][] doInBackground(String... params) {

            ...toda la función ObtenerInfo aqui dentro.
```

Gracias a todos.