# ¿Como ejecutar AsyncTask cada x segundos?

Tags: android, hilos, android-asynctask

Actualmente lo llamo una sola vez así:

```
hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();

        try {
            hiloconexion.execute(GET, "1").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

¿Cómo puedo llamarlo cada 5 segundos indefinidamente?

He intentado usar el handler como muestro a continuación pero la actividad se cierra y vuelve al main.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 5000;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

        try {
                hiloconexion.execute(GET, "1").get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);
```

También de esta otra forma propuesta por un compañero:

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(2000,2000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
                try {
                    hiloconexion.execute(GET, "1");
                } catch(Exception e){ Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());}
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                this.start();
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
```

Pero también se cierra la actividad sin errores.

La clase:

```
public class ObtenerWebService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[][]> {

        @Override
        protected String[][] doInBackground(String... params) {

            String cadena = params[0];
            URL url = null;

            if (params[1] == "1") {

                try {
                    url = new URL(cadena);
                    //Abrir la conexión
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" + " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");

                    int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                    if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        // preparo la cadena de entrada
                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());  
                        // la introduzco en un BufferedReader
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                            result.append(line);        
                        }

                        JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                        String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");

                        if (resultJSON.equals("1")) {
                        // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON
                            JSONArray infoJSON = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray("items");   
                            for (int i = 0; i < infoJSON.length(); i++) {
                                items[i][1] = infoJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("temp");

                            }
                        } else if (resultJSON.equals("2")) {}
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return items;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String s[][]) {
            super.onCancelled(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s[][]) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
```

Comment: En este enlace dicen como utilizar un timer para ejecutar una tarea cada x segundos.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el código con un handler pero solo consigo que se cierre la Actividad.

Comment: Se cierra la actividad porque salta alguna excepción? Que excepción te sale?

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano No me aparece ninguna excepción

Comment: porque utilizas el .get al hacer hiloconexion.execute(GET, "1").get();? ejecútalo como hiloconexion.execute(GET, "1") y revisa si estás capturando alguna excepción y por eso no "salta"

Comment: Este es el error: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)

Comment: Tienes que crear la tarea dentro del handler, justo antes de llamar a execute. Cada vez que hace una iteración, tienes que hacer el hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService(); ya que no puedes reutilizar la llamada asíncrona.

Comment: ánimo que ya casi lo tienes

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano se vuelve a cerrar la Actividad sin dar ningún mensaje de error de nuevo.

Comment: Entra en la llamada asíncrona? Pon unos puntos de interrupción para ver exactamente hasta donde se ejecuta y donde para

Comment: Primero que todo, crea un metodo que ejecute tu Task (el primer codigo de tu pregunta). Luego elimina el Handler e intenta utilizar la clase CountDownTimer. Su constructor recibe 2 parámetros. El primero la duración  y el segundo para el tick (puedes poner el mismo valor que la duracion) ambos valores deben ser en millis, donde 1000 es 1 segundo. En su metodo override OnFinish, vuelve a ejecutar el CountDownTimer con this.Start(); para hacer el timer infinito, seguido de tu metodo que ejecuta el Task.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano despues de poner varios puntos de interrupción, la actividad se cierra justo al entrar en esta if -> if (resultJSON.equals("1")) , he de decir que la función si la llamo una sola vez (sin el handler) no da error, por si te ayuda.

Comment: @Andrespengineer con tu propuesta también se cierra la Actividad y no da errores, he actualizado el código del primer mensaje con tu idea, revísala please.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he solucionado con AsyncTask fuera de OnCreate.

He sacado la función ObtenerWebService fuera de OnCreate y la llamo fuera con el Handler.

Gracias a todos.